# when to omit comma separators

Tags: r

cofv<- function(x)  sd(x)/mean(x)
There is no comma in this argument, and this is one thing that confuses me: Sometimes there is a comma to separate arguments, sometimes there isn’t. How is it determined whether I need a comma?

Comment: You need commas to separate multiple arguments. When you only have one argument, there is nothing to separate, thus there is no need for a comma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is only one argument, 'x'. You need to show other examples where there are commas that you don't understand. the function could be written:

```
cofv<- function(x) {
          sd(x)/mean(x) }
```